# Smooth refresh / display of updated table data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this function to populate a table with values from my database

And I have a filter so it's possible to search

But when I update my table, remove the old html and insert the new one, the page very briefly don't have anything, so it's blank, and it looks ugly if I am typing a long sentence like "bobby"

That's 5 keyup functions and 5 refreshes, I hope you understand what I am on about, I want it so it looks smooth

```
function getData(filter) {
$.ajax({
    url: '/Person/GetData',
    type: 'GET',
    data: { Filter: filter },
    success: function (data) {

        // Template for HTML
        var template = '';

        // Loop through the data
        $.each(data, function (index, value) {

            // Values from the database
            var personId = value['Id'];
            var firstName = value['FirstName'];
            var lastName = value['LastName'];
            var age = value['Age'];

            // Template for a new <tr>
            template += '<tr id="' + personId + '">' +
                            '<td col-lg-4">' + firstName + '</td>' +
                            '<td col-lg-4">' + lastName + '</td>' +
                            '<td col-lg-2">' + age + '</td>' +
                            '<td><a class="del-link col-lg-2">Slett</a></td>' +
                        '</tr>';

        });

        // Add the template to the table body
        $('tbody').html(template);
    }
});
```

}

Comment: You can use the `change` event in jQuery which check when input is change. For example it's won't check when key is pressed but when the input is unfocus and when the user hit enter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two separate issues here:

> But when I update my table, remove the old html and insert the new
>   one, the page very briefly don't have anything, so it's blank, and it
>   looks ugly if I am typing a long sentence like "bobby"

You should always expect AJAX requests (especially ones that subsequently insert content) to take longer than expected. You should use some kind of animation graphic to show that content is being loaded dynamically. There's plenty of ways to do this (search 'AJAX loader animation' on StackOverflow).

Your back-to-back look-ups aren't helping you either... essentially each subsequent look-up is emptying the page content, iterating the data, then inserting it into the DOM. Doing this multiple times (as you said) is not only unnecessary, but it puts a burden on your server and the client's browser.

> That's 5 keyup functions and 5 refreshes, I hope you understand what I
>   am on about, I want it so it looks smooth

You should use a setTimeout method so that a lookup is not performed on every keyup (when the keyup's are this sequential). This is simple to understand. It's essentially a "timer" that you start whenever your event (keyup) occurs. If the user triggers the keyup event while the timer is running, start/reset the timer. Once the timer has elapsed, perform the AJAX call.

e.g. using sudo coding, here's how I'd approach this (trying to keep it simple)

- onKeyUp event
- clear any previously set setTimeout()
- start new setTimeout() (calls a function after timer finishes)
- ---
- when setTimeout() executes the function...
- show animation
- perform AJAX call
- build content using data
- insert into DOM on success OR insert error message on failure
- hide animation (on both success or failure)